# js script not running on load

Tags: javascript, html

first time posting here so not too sure how this is going to go but here goes:

i took some code from a video on how to make a cool hacker-esque effect happen to some text when the cursor hovers over it, constantly changing each letter to a random letter. my plan was to adapt it so that it would have the effect when the page loads.

```
<h1 data-value="test">test</H1>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="format.css">

<script>
const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
document.querySelector("h1").onmouseover = event => {
let iterations = 0;
  
const interval = setInterval(() => {
event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText.split("")
    .map((letter, index) => {
        if (index + 4 < iterations / 3) {
            return event.target.dataset.value[index];
        }
  
        return letters[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)]
    })
    .join("");
  
    if(iterations >= (4 + event.target.dataset.value.length) * 3) clearInterval(interval);
    iterations +=1
}, 30);
}
</script>
```

testing the file below results in the expected result from the video - when the mouse hovers over the text, the effect plays.

to get the effect that i wanted, i changed `document.querySelector("h1").onmouseover = event => {...` to `document.querySelector("h1").onload = event => {...` although it just stops the effect from playing altogether. looking it up, i found that using window.onload should wait until everything on the page has loaded but i have absolutely no clue how to implement it without having to rewrite most of the code. i also tried changing it to be in the function text() and called it using `<h1 onload="text()">` although that didn't work either.

this feels like it's probably an easy fix but i've been looking for over an hour now to no avail

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get this animation on load you can try this:

```
const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

const init = () => {
    const target = document.querySelector("h1");
    let iterations = 0;
  
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
  target.innerText = target.innerText.split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
          if (index + 4 < iterations / 3) {
              return target.dataset.value[index];
          }

          return letters[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)]
      })
      .join("");

      if(iterations >= (4 + target.dataset.value.length) * 3) clearInterval(interval);
      iterations +=1
  }, 30);
}

init();
```